# Get RadioButton Title in Xcode AppleScript App

Tags: xcode, radio-button, applescript

I would like to get the title of a RadioButton, I connected an event called ChooseType_, to three RadioButtons, in which I would like to print in the output, the title of the chosen RadioButton

```
on ChooseType_(sender)
    set TitleOfRadio to title of sender as string
    print TitleOfRadio
    #Or
    set TitleOfRadio to sender's Title as string
    print TitleOfRadio
end ChooseType_
```

The two options that I wrote don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of AppleScriptObjC a property is a function so you have to add parentheses

```
on chooseType_(sender)
    set titleOfRadio to sender's title() as text
    log titleOfRadio
end chooseType_
```